# Disable file upload using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Recently, one of my clients website has been attacked. I noticed there, **in the tmp directory attacker uploaded php script**, where a user can upload images. My question is, is it possible to **stop uploading any files other than images using HTACCESS?** The website is built on Codeigniter.
Thanks  in advance. Any type of help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It can't use .HTACCESS to stop attacker(or hacker?) uploading script file.You should use Nginx(or others) configuration file to set script execute directory.

Please refer to https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/